# regex help to find word with character

Tags: regex

I would like to find strings that start with text and "-" charecter, find this:

```
2030-
OR
2232-
OR
2544-
etc
```

I tried:

```
 /(2030-|2232-|2544-|33-)/i
```

This not working with "-" or another characters, need help

Comment: If you want to match only strings that START with some numbers, do `^(...)`, AND you will need to escape the '-' character I think, so it would look like `/^(2030\-|2232\-|2544\-|33\-)/i`

Comment: you need to specify the language/tool you are using.regex implementation differs across languages/tools

Comment: @jazzpi: There is no need to escape `-`. It is only significant in character class `[]`, and there is way to avoid escaping.

Comment: @jazzpi You only (SFAIK) need to escape the hyphen if it is inside of a character class, and then only if it is neither the first (excluding negated character classes) nor the last character of the character class. It doesn't hurt anything to escape it, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^.*?-/
```

is the most general construct

This will match any string from the beginning of the string until the first "-"

Answer (score 0):

Try this general `regex`:

```
/(\d+\-)/i
```

explanation

> ***`\d`***
>   Matches any decimal digit.

Answer (score 0):

This reg should work for you:

```
/^(?:2030|2232|2544|33)-$/
```

Make sure anchors `^` and `$` are placed like this.